# Test to see if I should free memory or not

Tags: c, pointers

I am passing a pointer to a char array to my method, as well as a value for the actual height of the char array. I am looping through to see if all values are 0, if they are then return 0, else return 1.

The method is used as a test to see if I should free memory or not and set the pointer to null if it is full of 0's. The issue i am having is that the program should have "some unfree" memory at the end, so I have no idea whether or not its doing it correctly - and gdb I struggle with immensely.

Thanks for reading

```
int shouldBeNull(char *charPointer, int sizeOfCharArray)
{
    int isIn = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(i < sizeOfCharArray){
        if(*charPointer != '0'){
            isIn = 1;
            break;
        }
        i++;
        charPointer++;
    }   
    return isIn;     
}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing isIn at the end of the loop ???

Comment: You need to increment *charPointer in order to have the pointer iterate across all the elements in the array. Also heed @Paul R's advice.

Comment: sorry guys, i didnt copy and paste from my code, just typed, that will teach me :D

Comment: Find a GDB Cheat sheet, and become familiar with some of the basic commands. It's overkill for testing just this function but it'll be useful for later on.

Comment: +1 for specifically asking to not post solutions

Comment: +1 : What Raj More said.

Answer (score 5):

When you say "...all values are zero...", I was assuming that you meant binary values of zero, rather than the character '0'...

```
if(*charPointer != '0'){
```

This is the zero-digit character (ASCII 0x31) rather than a NUL character (ASCII 0x00). If you were trying to check for zero bytes, try the following:

```
if (*charPointer != '\0') {
```

Also, you're not incrementing or offsetting your character pointer `charPointer`, so you're always testing the first character.

```
if (*charPointer++ != '\0) {
```

...or...

```
if (*(charPointer + i) != '\0) {
```

Comment: Or just `if (*charPointer)` or `if (*charPointer != 0)`

Comment: so if i am checking for the charachter 0 then my way was correct?

also, i am incrementing the pointer at the end?

Comment: @sbsp : yes, your code was checking for the zero digit character correctly, with the possible exception that it doesn't account for a terminating null character (0x00) at the end of the string - assuming that your buffer points to a null-terminated string...

Answer (score 4):

You are not incrementing charPointer

Comment: @sbsp : Your original version didn't show that. The edited version now shows that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

- You're not returning 1 if not all the values are 0
- Instead of setting `isIn` and breaking out of the loop, you can just return 1 from the condition